# pygame rectangle collision detection does not work

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I am trying to add a platform to my game so that once you hit it the player stays on the platform until it fall off in which case it would hit the ground. The jump does work but the collision does not

I have tried adding some of the typical types of collision detectors below but they all have down sides

```
class Platform:
    def __init__(self, x, y, background):
        self.xpos = x
        self.ypos = y
        self.picture = background
        self.picture = pygame.transform.scale(self.picture, (500, 100))
        self.rect = self.picture.get_rect()

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))

class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y, pic_one, pic_two, pic_three, pic_four):
        self.xpos = x
        self.ypos = y
        self.speed_y = 0
        self.speed_x = 0
        self.picture = pic_one
        self.picture_one = pic_one
        self.picture_two = pic_two
        self.picture_three = pic_three
        self.picture_four = pic_four
        self.on_ground = True
        self.picture = pygame.transform.scale(self.picture, (100, 100))
        self.rect = self.picture.get_rect()

    def update(self):
        self.xpos += self.speed_x
        self.ypos += self.speed_y

        GRAVITY = 0.9

        self.speed_y += GRAVITY  # Accelerate downwards.
        self.xpos += self.speed_x 
        self.ypos += self.speed_y


        if self.ypos >= 620:
            self.ypos = 620
            self.speed_y = 0
            self.on_ground = True


        if self.on_ground == True:
            self.speed_y = 0


    def jump(self):
        if self.on_ground:
            self.on_ground = False
            self.speed_y = -20#Makes you move upwards

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))

    def is_collided_with(self, sprite):
        return self.rect.colliderect(sprite.rect)

player_one = Player(30, 600, player_one_first_pic)
wood_platform = Platform(400, 400, platform_pic)
while True:
    [...]
```

this is the typical type of collision I would try and have used but the if statement appears to never happen

```
if player_one.rect.bottom == wood_platform.rect.top:
    player_one.on_ground = True
```

another on which I have tried which is detecting if the rectangles collide
and the if statement is True even when the rectangles are not colliding

```
if player_one.is_collided_with(wood_platform):
     player_one.on_ground = True
```

this method I am not comfortable with doing because its insufficient

```
if player_one.ypos == 600:
    player_one.on_ground = True
```

The actual results for the method that I used were that the player did not collide with the wooden platform at all

(Here is a diagram if you do need a little bit more of an understanding:) 
[image: player_platform]
Checks for collision but does not appear to work

```
if player_one.rect.y == wood_platform.rect.y:
        print(True)
        player_one.on_ground = True
        on_platform = True

    else:
        on_platform = False
```

changes after each update

```
self.rect.x = self.xpos
self.rect.y = self.ypos
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for me problem is that you use `self.xpos`, `self.ypos` to move object and you don't change values in `self.rect` (`self.rect.x`, `self.rect.y`) but you use `self.rect` to check collision.

You have to set

```
self.rect.x = self.xpos
self.rect.y = self.ypos
```

before you check collision.

And you have to do this for all moving objects. Maybe it is better to do this after every move.

---

You could use only `self.rect.x`, `self.rect.y` (instead of `self.xpos, self.ypos`) but it can keeps only integer values. You use float value in gravity and `self.rect.x`, `self.rect.y` would round down position and gives not so smooth animation.

But objects which don't use float gravity or float speed could use only `self.rect` to keep position.

Comment: So if I now do if player_one.rect.y (player one is the object)  == wood_platform.rect.y would that work because thats what I feel most comfy doing

Comment: you can do it - but it may not works if you move player more than one pixel in every move. In one moment `player_one.rect.y` can be smaller than `wood_platform.rect.y` (so it doesn't collide) and in next moment it can be bigger than `wood_platform.rect.y` (so it collides) and `==` will not catch it. Better use `self.rect.colliderect(other.rect)`. It can also recognize collision on left/right side or when you jump and player's head touch platform at bottom - so it should stop moving up and start moving down.

Comment: Ok, I have added the code block above but this appears to still not happen

Comment: do you use `self.rect.x` , `self.rect.y` in Player and in Platform ?

Comment: Yes I can confirm that I do

Comment: maybe use `print(player_one.rect, wood_platform.rect)` before  `if player_one.rect.y == wood_platform.rect.y:` to see values.

Comment: but as I sad before problem can be `==`. In one moment you may have `player.rect.y < wood_platform.rect.y` and in next moment `player.rect.y > wood_platform.rect.y` and `==` will not catch collision. Better use `rect.colliderect()` or at least use `>=` instead of `==`

Comment: I have used that before though and it the if statement never happened for the collider. Its the is_collided_with function at the top

Comment: I have seem another problem though. when the player hits the bottom of the rectangle it stops when it should only stop when it hits the top of the platform

Comment: it didn't work because you didn't use `rect.x`, `rect.y` for player and platform - And I think you still may not use it for platform. use `print()` to see values in variables.

Comment: to jump on platform you can check collision only when you move down (fall `self.speed_y > 0`) and not check collision when you move up (`self.speed_y < 0`).

Comment: the self.speed_y > 0 thing does work but the problem is that the player is still slowly falling through the platform

Comment: if something doesn't work corectly then use `print()` to see values in variables - or learn how to use debuger.  Position depends on speed and you set speed to zero but you still add Gravity (which is not zero) to speed and you add it to position. You should check `on_ground` before you add speed to position. Or if you check collison then you can get top of platform and assing as bottom of player. `player.rect.bottom = wood_platform.rect.top`

Comment: I have made it stay on the platform but when its not on the platform its floating

Comment: do you mean on ground ? create plaftorm in place of ground.

Comment: do not worry I got there in the end and it does work now

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me

Answer (score 0):

I often have the same problem in my job. Checking if numbers are equal might fail when using floats. You could try to change this

```
if player_one.rect.bottom == wood_platform.rect.top:
    player_one.on_ground = True
```

to this:

```
margin = 0.001 # Whatever amount you feel comfy with.
if wood_platform.rect.top*(1-margin) <= player_one.rect.bottom <= wood_platform.rect.top*(1+margin):
    player_one.on_ground = True
```